# using OOP approach to create plugin but stuck at making hyperlinks to work

Tags: menus, mvc

I am new to wordpress development so please be patient if my question sounds simple or ridiculous, since I have been doing object oriented programming in PHP so i wanted to use the OOP approach in wordpress plugin development as well and came across [Boilerplate](https://github.com/tommcfarlin/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate). I have gone through the code in detail but I am still confused.

At present it comes with a view of `admin.php`, i wanted to create another page for testing purpose so i created a file view/`admin2.php`, I then want to create a hyperlink in `admin.php` to redirect the user to `admin2.php`, how can i do it? if i simply do the following, it does not work and gives me 404 error

```
<a href="admin2.php">go to admin 2</a>
```

I know i can create a sub menu but i do not want to do that yet. I will really appreciate any help here.

**UPDATE**

This is what my `admin.php` looks like

```
<?php
echo '<a href="'. plugins_url( 'admin2.php' , __FILE__ ) .'">Go to admin 2 page</a>';
?>
```

This is what my `admin2.php` looks like

```
<?php
echo '<a href="'. plugins_url( 'admin.php' , __FILE__ ) .'">Go to admin page</a>';
?>
```